# Android Service stops working after a certain point in code when called from activity

Tags: android

I am creating an android app which includes an activity which shows a list of tweets. When the activity is created a service is started which runs an async task to fetch the tweets and then passes them back to the activity using a broadcast.

Originally I had this working, but when I went to try it again yesterday the tweets were not showing up. After some debugging, I realised that the service wasn't executing all of my code. I did this by moving about a log message in my code to see the last place that it would print out in the logcat, this is shown in my service code below.

**Does anyone know why this service is stopping or what the problem is exactly?**

Code for service:

```
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
   {
      Log.i(TAG,"The service has started!");
      new GetTweets().execute();
      return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate()
   {
      super.onCreate();
      myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
   {
      return null;
   }

   private class GetTweets extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
   {
      ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
      Tweet tweet;

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String s)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(s);
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
      {

         try
         {

            List<twitter4j.Status> statuses;
            OAuth2Token bearerToken = null;

            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
                    .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
                    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_SECRET)
                    .setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(true);
            Configuration config = cb.build();
            tf = new TwitterFactory(config);
            twitter = tf.getInstance();

            bearerToken = twitter.getOAuth2Token();

            twitter.setOAuth2Token(bearerToken);

            Paging page = new Paging(1, NUM_TWEETS);

            statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(name, page);

            //Last line that is executed.
            Log.i(TAGF, "Nearly Finished");

            text = getAllTweets(statuses);
            tweet = getLatestTweet(statuses);


            Intent sendTweet = new Intent();
            sendTweet.setAction(AURORA_ACTION);
            sendTweet.putExtra("latestTweet", tweet);
            sendTweet.putStringArrayListExtra("allTweets", text);

            sendBroadcast(sendTweet);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sent tweets", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


         } catch (TwitterException e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch (ParseException parse)
         {

         }

         return null;

      }
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.aurora);

      myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

      getActionBar().setTitle("AuroraWatch UK Tweets");
      getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.style.CodeFont));

      Intent getTweets = new Intent(this,AuroraService.class);
      startService(getTweets);
      Toast.makeText(this, "Activity Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }

   @Override
   protected void onPause()
   {
      super.onPause();
      unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();

      myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
      {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
         {
            ArrayList<String> tweets=null;
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(AuroraService.AURORA_ACTION))
            {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Received tweets", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               tweets = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("allTweets");
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tweets);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);

         }
      };

      IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter();
      myFilter.addAction(AuroraService.AURORA_ACTION);
      registerReceiver(myReceiver,myFilter);
   }
```

**EDIT**: getAllTweets () method:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllTweets(List<twitter4j.Status> statuses)
      {
         ArrayList<String> myTweets = new ArrayList<String>();

         for (twitter4j.Status status: statuses)
         {
            String tweet = status.getText();
            myTweets.add(tweet);
         }

         return myTweets;
      }
```

Comment: A started service can use the startForeground API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory. By default services are background, meaning that if the system needs to kill them to reclaim more memory (such as to display a large page in a web browser), they can be killed without too much harm.

Comment: Can you show the code of `getAllTweets()` ? Your service might killed by the system as @Harish said, but it may also crash (in which case you should find a stack trace in LogCat) or freeze (in case you do network operation that blocks infinitely)

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! I will post getAllTweets() code now.

Comment: I have a few other services in my app also, so if i use startForeground for all of them would that be ok?

Comment: Is there any way else to ensure that the service runs fully each time it is started other than the foreground service api? I am kind of confused by it